# Why the CPU time is different in other threads

Tags: multithreading, process, cpu-time

I ran the top -H -p for a process which gave me the few threads with LWPs.
But when I sort the results with smallest PID first, I noticed the time in first thread is constant but the other threads time is changing. Why TIME+ is different?

`PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
16989 root      20   0  106m  28m 2448 S  0.0  0.2   0:22.31 glusterfs 
16990 root      20   0  106m  28m 2448 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 glusterfs 
16992 root      20   0  106m  28m 2448 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 glusterfs 
16993 root      20   0  106m  28m 2448 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 glusterfs
16997 root      20   0  106m  28m 2448 S  0.0  0.2   0:11.71 glusterfs 
17010 root      20   0  106m  28m 2448 S  0.0  0.2   0:21.07 glusterfs 
17061 root      20   0  106m  28m 2448 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 glusterfs`

Comment: It's not an uncommon pattern for the first thread to create a pool of thread and then just wait while the real work is done by the threads in that pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why TIME+ is different?

Because different threads are doing different percentages of the work.  There could be a number of reasons for this<sup>1</sup>, but the most likely is that the application (glusterfs) is not attempting to distribute work evenly across the worker threads.

It is not something to worry about.  It doesn't matter which thread does the work if the work level (see the %CPU) is negligible.

---

<sup>1 - If someone had the time and inclination, they could look at the source code of glusterfs to try to understand its behavior.  However, I don't think the effort is warranted.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Because the time column referes to the time consumed by a process, so when a process time does not change it probably means that this process is "sleeping" or simply waiting for an other process to finish, but there could be many more reasons.

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm

> TIME:
>
> Total CPU time the task has used since it started. If cumulative mode
> is on, this also includes the CPU time used by the process's children
> which have died. You can set cumulative mode with the S command line
> option or toggle it with the interactive command S. The header line
> will then be changed to CTIME.